# android firebase start listing data equal to entered letter

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

There is a problem with the list inside the "if" it doesn't work I get an error this:java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List

```
 private FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private DocumentReference productSearchRef = rootRef.collection("products").document("qQIJ9oGjlwwqNObfVV6U");
private CollectionReference productsRef = rootRef.collection("products");

  MutableLiveData<List<String>> getProductNameListMutableLiveData() {
    MutableLiveData<List<String>> productNameListMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    productSearchRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(productNameListTask -> {
        if (productNameListTask.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = productNameListTask.getResult();

            if (document.exists()) {
                List<String> productNameList = (List<String>) document.get("name");

                productNameListMutableLiveData.setValue(productNameList);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, productNameListTask.getException().getMessage());
        }
    });
    return productNameListMutableLiveData;
}![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a5Tl.jpg)
```

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find an [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) that will help achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: What isn't working about the code you shared? Specifically, when you step through it in a debugger, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @AlexMamo thank you that's what i want.  Finally i did and works fully.

Comment: @AlexMamo hey could you help me i edited question i tried same as your code blocks but i get an error while creating a list in if sentence

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo İ haven't done any change belong to your code but i get this error:"java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List"in the second if sentence which is document.exists also before this i suspected i couldn't write true connection but i try to get single value before document exists i get the data from firestore but when the comes document exists it is thrown exception which is write up

Comment: Then please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo i edited and added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List"

In the second if statement, because the type of the "name" field in the database is String and **not** a List, hence that error. There is no way in Java in which you can convert a String into a List. To solve this, you should get the value of the "name" field according to its data type. So please change the following line of code:

```
List<String> productNameList = (List<String>) document.get("name");
```

Into:

```
String productNameList = document.getString("name");
```

So something like this will do the trick:

```
private FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private DocumentReference productSearchRef = rootRef.collection("products").document("qQIJ9oGjlwwqNObfVV6U");
private CollectionReference productsRef = rootRef.collection("products");

MutableLiveData<List<String>> getProductNameListMutableLiveData() {
MutableLiveData<List<String>> productNameListMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    productsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(productNameListTask -> {
        if (productNameListTask.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot snapshot = productNameListTask.getResult();
             for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : snapshot) {
                 if (document.exists()) {
                     String name = document.getString("name");
                     productNameList.add(name);
                 }
             }
             productNameListMutableLiveData.setValue(productNameList);
        } else {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, productNameListTask.getException().getMessage());
        }
    });
    return productNameListMutableLiveData;
```

Comment: Thanks again it was helpful. most important thing my  list initialiaze was wrong i fix that and i did your tips. now  it is exactly like a what i want